# Python Find a day dates between a range of two dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime, python-dateutil

I'm working on a project using python3 in which I have to consume an api and need to fetch the data for a specific Day of the week between a range a date.

So, the example input parameters are:

```
firstDay = '1-January-2000'
lastDay = '22-february-2000'
weekDay = 'Monday'
```

So, the date will be included in the API response but nothing has any information for the day. So, I have to get all the dates for a specific day like `Monday` between a date range.

According to the example above, how can I get the dates for all `Mondays` between `firstDay` and `lastDay`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import time

firstDay = '1-January-2000'
lastDay = '22-february-2000'
weekDay = 'Monday'

firstDay = datetime.strptime(firstDay, '%d-%B-%Y') 
lastDay = datetime.strptime(lastDay, '%d-%B-%Y')
dates = [firstDay + timedelta(days=x) for x in range((lastDay-firstDay).days + 1) if (firstDay + timedelta(days=x)).weekday() == time.strptime(weekDay, '%A').tm_wday]
```

output

```
dates
[datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 3, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 10, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 17, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 24, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 31, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2000, 2, 7, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2000, 2, 14, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2000, 2, 21, 0, 0)]
```

The output in format `weekDay-Month-year`

```
[d.strftime("%A-%B-%Y") for d in dates] 

['Monday-January-2000',
 'Monday-January-2000',
 'Monday-January-2000',
 'Monday-January-2000',
 'Monday-January-2000',
 'Monday-February-2000',
 'Monday-February-2000',
 'Monday-February-2000']
```

output in `firstDay` format: `1-January-2000`

```
[d.strftime("%-d-%B-%Y") for d in dates]   
['3-January-2000',
 '10-January-2000',
 '17-January-2000',
 '24-January-2000',
 '31-January-2000',
 '7-February-2000',
 '14-February-2000',
 '21-February-2000']
```

Comment: I have to utilize the parameters, like `firstDay & lastDay` in the format `1-January-2000` and `weekDay` as day name.

Comment: awesome list comprehension here. and use of `%B` and `%A`... great pythonic answer

Comment: How can I generate the response in the format like `firstDay` as `1-January-2000` so it can as: `weekDay-Month-year`?

Comment: Hi @frankegoesdown, there's another issue comes in and that's the leading zero for `day` can I get the dates like `01-January-2000` as `1-January-2000`, because the leading zero for the day is creating a problem for further implementation.

Answer (score 2):

please try this:

```py
import datetime
import calendar

def get_all_weekdays_between_range(firstDay, lastDay, weekDay):
    month_name_to_num = {v.lower(): k for k, v in enumerate(calendar.month_name)}
    day_name_to_num = {v.lower(): k for k, v in enumerate(calendar.day_name)}

    def parse_date(dateStr):
        parts = dateStr.split('-')
        return datetime.date(int(parts[2]), month_name_to_num[parts[1].lower()], int(parts[0]))

    first = parse_date(firstDay)
    last = parse_date(lastDay)

    result = []
    current = first
    while current <= last:
        if calendar.weekday(current.year, current.month, current.day) == day_name_to_num[weekDay.lower()]:
            result.append(current)
        current += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return result


firstDay = '1-January-2000'
lastDay = '22-february-2000'
weekDay = 'Monday'

all_days = get_all_weekdays_between_range(firstDay,lastDay,weekDay)
for day in all_days:
    print(day)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the datetime library in python, this is a perfect scenario for it. It holds all information about years months and days and can even do calculations of dates. For example finding how many days are between two dates. It can also convert dates into whatever format you want.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Here's an answer to your question

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
dstart = datetime.strptime('1-January-2000', '%d-%B-%Y') 
dend= datetime.strptime('22-February-2000', '%d-%B-%Y')
ans = (dend - dstart).days / 7
if int(ans) + 2/7 <= ans:
    ans = int(ans) + 1
else:
    ans = int(ans)
print(ans)
```

Comment: you count the days, OP wanted to get all the dates